# Rotate location of SVG group element in JavaScript without rotating whole image

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a map drawn in SVG that I use matrix transformations to rotate based on certain mouse events. When I click on parts of the map, I have annotations that are drawn (in a group element separate from the rotated image).

Right now, I can move those annotations with the map when I drag it by just sending the event on to a JavaScript function to do that shift as a separate action. I'd like to do the same sort of thing when I rotate and scale the underlying map, but am unsure how to proceed - obviously I don't want to rotate the whole annotation image; I just want to shift it to match the updated map. It seems like maybe I need to figure out how to calculate the effects of the map transformation on the X/Y coordinates of a single point and then apply that calculation to the annotation location. I can't seem to find any resources that might help in figuring out how to do that.

Here's a blog article that I wrote talking about how I manipulate the underlying map: http://justindthomas.wordpress.com/category/flower-nfa/

The live example in that article doesn't work right now (I moved the location of the JavaScript files), but it should give some useful context to my question.

Comment: If you found your own solution, you should put it in as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just doing the math by hand. Here's the function I used for posterity:

```
getRadiusAngle: function(referenceX, referenceY, centerX, centerY) {                
    var width = centerX - referenceX;
    var height = centerY - referenceY;
    var angle, radius;

    if(centerY > referenceY) {
        if(centerX > referenceX) {
            angle = Math.PI - Math.atan(Math.abs(height/width));
            radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2));
        } else if (centerX < referenceX) {
            angle = Math.atan(Math.abs(height/width));
            radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2));
        } else if (centerX == referenceX) {
            angle = Math.PI / 2;
            radius = height;
        }
    } else if(centerY < referenceY) {
        if(centerX > referenceX) {
            angle = Math.PI + Math.atan(Math.abs(height/width));
            radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2));
        } else if (centerX < referenceX) {
            angle = (2 * Math.PI) - Math.atan(Math.abs(height/width));
            radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2));
        } else if (centerX == referenceX) {
            angle = Math.PI * 1.5;
            radius = Math.abs(height);
        }
    } else if(centerY == referenceY) {
        if(centerX > referenceX) {
            angle = Math.PI;
            radius = width;
        } else if (centerX < referenceX) {
            angle = 0;
            radius = Math.abs(width);
        } else if(centerX == referenceX) {
            angle = 0;
            radius = 0;
        }
    }

    return({
        "radius": radius, 
        "angle": angle
    })
},
```

For rotate operations I then used:

```
var calcwidth = annotations[i].getAttribute("calcwidth");
var matrix = annotations[i].getCTM();

var referenceX = (matrix.e + (calcwidth/2));
var referenceY = (matrix.f + 32);

var ra = this.getRadiusAngle(referenceX, referenceY, pointerX, pointerY);

var current_angle = ra.angle;
var radius = ra.radius

var newX, newY;
if(radius == 0) {
    newX = matrix.e;
    newY = matrix.f;
} else {      
    var new_angle = current_angle + -radians;  

    newX = (pointerX + (radius * Math.cos(new_angle))) - (calcwidth/2);
    newY = (pointerY + -(radius * Math.sin(new_angle))) - 32;
}

annotations[i].setAttribute("transform", "translate(" 
    + newX + " " + newY + ")");
```

For scaling, I used a similar strategy.